# Initialise and mutate array in one line

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to get a data set and `splice` off some irrelevant lines, preferably in one line.

Using

```
let data = tgSh.getDataRange().getValues();
data.splice(0, headers.getRow());
```

...works fine but combining the two lines as:

```
let data = tgSh.getDataRange().getValues().splice(0, headers.getRow());
```

...just returns the spliced values and not a mutated `data` array.

Is there anyway to do this? Not the end of the world but just learning as I go

Comment: Use `slice()` instead of `splice()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `slice()`. It doesn't mutate, it returns a new array. Butince you no longer have a reference to the original array, you can't tell the difference (except for some extra memory allocation, which will be collected quickly by GC).

```
let data = tgSh.getDataRange().getValues().slice(0, headers.getRow());
```